# From orthogonal group to orthonormal frames

Tags: vector-spaces, manifolds, orthogonality, orthonormal

Define the orthonormal frame of a space $R^n$ to be a set of vectors ($b_1$, $b_2$, ..., $b_n$) if these vectors together form an orthonormal basis of $R^n$, and denote this frame to be $F_n$.

Similarly, define positively oriented orthonormal frames to be $F_{n}^{+}$, just that this time only positively oriented bases are considered.

How do you identify $F_n$ with orthogonal group $O(n)$, and how do you identify $F_{n}^{+}$ with special orthogonal group $SO(n)$?

I a bit confused how far should this "identification" goes. For example, for the first part of question, if I can just pick a random orthogonal matrix from the given $O(n)$ group, then I can get a set of orthogonal basis of $R^n$, and finally normalize it to get the orthonormal version? Since there is no extra requirements on which specific orthonormal frame I should get?

For the latter part of question I am indeed confused on how to get $F_{n}^{+}$ from $SO(n)$.

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: These are principal homogeneous spaces, or torsors, over the groups in question. That means you need to pick a point to get an identification with the group.

Comment: The orthogonal matrices take the standard basis to one of the $F_n$. Likewise, for the positively oriented ones.